# Google Sheets: How to merge two columns into one, alternating input from each column and skipping blanks

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

So I've seen a few other posts on here asking basically the same question but I can't seem to get it to work. As I mentioned above, I'm trying to take the input from two columns and put that information into a third column, alternating between the first two columns and skipping blanks. I've put a screen shot for an example. Perhaps it'd be easier just to write a python script.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use Flatten to merge the two columns then Query to remove blanks:

```
=query(flatten(B1:C), "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good practice to always explicitly specify the `headers` parameter in `query()`. In this instance, omitting it will cause the first result value to be blank when cell `B1` is blank. The `select` clause is optional and can be left out here.

Comment: Good points, thank you. I have re-done the screen shot to match the edited formula but if I enter flatten in lower case it actually appears in upper case as in the screen shot

Comment: Move the cursor to the end of the formula before pressing Enter to avoid Google Sheets changing the letter case of the function.